# Javascript SDK error and Canvas resizing issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I'm trying to resize the Canvas for an app but I can't get the JS SDK or the fixed height setting to work.  In the console for chrome I see:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createClass2' on XFBML:13
```

Firefox:

```
FB.Type.createClass2 is not a function on XFBML:13
```

I have my app Canvas setting on fluid for width, and fixed at 1200px (which has no effect).
Note: there is no Settable option.

Here is my JS SDK include.  It's right after the <head> tag

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '188042251295955', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the ...
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(100); 
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

I would appreciate any help on this.  If you can spot any errors/missing settings, that would be great.

Comment: Which function and how actually do you call, when getting an error?

Comment: FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(100) is the only one.  As far as I can tell, I'm not getting to make any calls. I'm pretty sure it is erroring out when loading the script, because fbAsyncInit never gets called.

Comment: Are you sure, you can just call it, not in some another callback?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue here.  The JS SDK was erroring out when the script was loading because of (stupidly included) old scripts  on the page.

#1: Old share button code.

```
function facebookShare(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
//initialize facebookShare
facebookShare(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
```

#2: Facebook FeatureLoader (deprecated JS SDK)

```
<script src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```